# Show items with no data in Google spreadsheet pivot table

Tags: google, jira, pivot

I have a google spreadsheet. It contains multiple columns. Column A has list of Jira stories. Column D has the status of each stories. Column K has the epic ID of each of the stories in Column A. I want to sum up the story points of each epic but only if the status of the story is closed. I want a table to show one column with all the Epic ID and their corresponding completed Story points. I tried a pivot. But if the value is 0, the pivot table does not show it. Can someone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please note that the appropriate tag to use when asking questions about Google spreadsheets is [tag:google-sheets], and not [tag:google].  The attached tags should be about what is being asked not about the words used, so in this case [tag:jira] should be removed. Please describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet including the locale / country setting as it affects stuff like the function parameter and decimal separators among other stuff. Add some sample data, and show the expected result.